# Is Colding-Minicozzi entropy continuous w.r.t. $C^\infty$ convergenge?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, entropy, geometric-analysis, hypersurfaces

For an hypersurface $\Sigma^n \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ the *entropy* introduced by Colding and Minicozzi (see [their paper](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/2012/175-2/p07)) is defined as

$$
\lambda(\Sigma) := \sup_{x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \\ t_0 \in \mathbb{R}_+} \frac{1}{(4 \pi t_0)^{\frac{n}{2}}}\int_{\Sigma} e^{-\frac{|x - x_0|^2}{4t_0}}.
$$

If $(\Sigma_j)_j$ is a sequence of surfaces smoothly converging to a hypersurface $\Sigma$, is it true that $\lim_{j \rightarrow \infty}\lambda(\Sigma_j) = \lambda(\Sigma)$ ?

**EDIT**: I guess the answer is negative. In fact take $\tilde{\Sigma}$ a hyperplane with a sphere connected by a small neck and define $\Sigma_j$ to be  $\tilde{\Sigma}$ translated in such a way that as $j$ increases, the sphere escape at infinity. Then the entropy of each $\Sigma_j$ is going to be equal to the entropy of $\tilde{\Sigma}$ which I believe should be strictly greater than 1, while $\lambda(\Sigma)=1$. Is this a valid counterexample?

Comment: Your counter example shows that smooth convergence on compacts sets is not enough. The result might still be true for some other notion of convergence which doesn't allows such "loss of mass at infinity".